# LWT simple interaction with a subprocess

Tags: subprocess, ocaml, ocaml-lwt

Here is a simple program that uses the `Unix` module to interact with a subprocess. I just launch a `cat` shell command, send it a string and read it back:

```
#load "unix.cma";; (* Needed if you are in the toplevel *)

let () =
    let sin, sout, serr = Unix.open_process_full "cat" [||]  in
    output_string sout "test\n";
    flush sout;
    input_line sin |> print_string;
    flush stdout;
    Unix.close_process_full (sin, sout, serr) |> ignore;;
```

Recently I started studying the `Lwt` library, and I wanted to reproduce the same functionality with it. I though that the following should have exactly the same result:

```
    #use "topfind";;                (*                            *)
    #thread;;                       (* Also only for the toplevel *)
    #require "lwt.simple-top";;     (*                            *)

    let () =
        let open Lwt in
        let process = Lwt_process.open_process_full ( "cat" , [||]  ) in
        Lwt_io.write_line process#stdin "test\n"
        >>= ( fun ()  -> Lwt_io.flush process#stdin  )
        >>= ( fun ()  -> Lwt_io.read  process#stdout )
        >>= ( fun str -> Lwt_io.print str            )
        >>= ( fun ()  -> Lwt_io.flush Lwt_io.stdout  )
        |> Lwt_main.run
```

But it doesn't work as I expect it to -- apparently it reads and then prints an empty string.

I guess I have some fundamental confusion on how `Lwt` should work, but I cannot figure it out. Can someone show me how one can communicate with a subprocess using `Lwt`?

Comment: You're passing it incorrectly: Need something like: `Lwt_process.open_process_full ("cat", [|"cat"; "Makefile"|])`

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian he's running `cat` with no arguments so it will copy stdin to stdout (of `cat`.)

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Yeah `[|"cat"; "Makefile"|]` works and dumps the Makefile. But that is not what I want -- as @RichN said, I'd like to use `cat` as stdin -> stdout program. I also tried `[|"cat"|]` -- that blocks the program for some bizarre reason...

Answer (score 2):

Use `Lwt_process.shell` to make a proper command, in your case, the proper command is the following:

```
Lwt_process.shell "cat";;
- : Lwt_process.command = ("", [|"/bin/sh"; "-c"; "cat"|])
```

Also, I suspect, that after you will run your program in a proper way, you will be wondering, why is your program blocking. This reason is because `cat` process will not finish until you write an EOF to it's input channel. That's why the `Lwt_io.read` call will not ever finish. A solution would be to close the `stdin` channel.